# Does Visual Studio 2008 support classic ASP development?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp-classic

Does visual studio 2008 support classic asp development?

It's been years since I created a classic ASP website and I was wondering if I can use my current toolset or if I have to resign myself to notepad.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as others have mentioned, VS 2008 SP1 supports classic ASP.

However, if, like me, you find it a bit of a behemoth for the relatively simple classic ASP, give  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) a try - no need to resign yourself to plain old Notepad!

Answer (score 6):

I know VS 2008 now includes Intellisense and Debugging feature for classic ASP, so thats make me think Yes.

Be sure you get the Service Pack 1 version.

Comment: brillant thanks, I read a post online which seemed to suggest that classic ASP wasn't going to be supported... must of misunderstood

Comment: It wasn't supported until SP1

Answer (score 4):

Yes, VS 2008 SP1 does support ASP.  You need SP1 because they had removed some of the intellisense, but added it back in SP1

Answer (score 3):

On a side note that might be relevant, Visual Studio 2010 also supports classic asp

Answer (score 1):

This is a good reference for setting up a classic ASP site in Visual Studio 2008:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/DebugVBScriptVS2008.aspx

Additionally, I had to give "Everyone" access to the Virtual Directory in IIS that I setup in my local machine for it to run correctly:

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=181211