# does anybody did debug classic asp in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-code

I've seen several classic ASP extensions on VS code for classic ASP but none for debugging. I'm new to VS Code and i was wondering how to debug a legacy classic ASP code on it.

I've found how to debug ASP code on VS17, but i'd rather debug it on VS Code since it's a lighter IDE.

Does anybody did debug classic asp in Visual Studio Code successfully? If so can anybody give me some directions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [has anybody been able to debug asp classic code with visual studio 2005 or later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958968/has-anybody-been-able-to-debug-asp-classic-code-with-visual-studio-2005-or-later)

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for debugging Classic ASP in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) but it has extensive support for [debugger extensions through the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=debugger&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

Unfortunately, no one has created a debugger extension for Classic ASP at present, so for now you're stuck with Visual Studio or good old `Response.Write` `Response.End` statements.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart, I've found this [one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jtjoo.classic-asp-html). it seems very good ranked

Comment: @ValmirCinquini that doesn’t give you the ability to debug Classic ASP in Visual Studio Code, just allows syntax highlighting and some syntax support.